# Python using enumerate inside list comprehension

Tags: python, list, iteration, list-comprehension

Lets suppose I have a list like this:

```
mylist = ["a","b","c","d"]
```

To get the values printed along with their index I can use Python's `enumerate` function like this

```
>>> for i,j in enumerate(mylist):
...     print i,j
...
0 a
1 b
2 c
3 d
>>>
```

Now, when I try to use it inside a `list comprehension` it gives me this error

```
>>> [i,j for i,j in enumerate(mylist)]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    [i,j for i,j in enumerate(mylist)]
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So, my question is: what is the correct way of using enumerate inside list comprehension?

Answer (score 197, accepted):

Try this:

```
[(i, j) for i, j in enumerate(mylist)]
```

You need to put `i,j` inside a tuple for the list comprehension to work. Alternatively, given that `enumerate()` *already* returns a tuple, you can return it directly without unpacking it first:

```
[pair for pair in enumerate(mylist)]
```

Either way, the result that gets returned is as expected:

```
> [(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd')]
```

Comment: Not mandatory to be a tuple. Any expression using i and j that returns a value will do

Comment: use of enumeration is great, how about making it more efficient using itertools

Comment: Just remember that a tuple is built by the `,` **not** the `()`. So "putting `i,j` inside a tuple" makes no sense, since `i,j` is already a tuple! The problem is the the list comp parser needs the parens for statement group.

Answer (score 48):

Just to be really clear, this has nothing to do with `enumerate` and everything to do with list comprehension syntax.

This list comprehension returns a list of tuples:

```
[(i,j) for i in range(3) for j in 'abc']
```

this a list of dicts:

```
[{i:j} for i in range(3) for j in 'abc']
```

a list of lists:

```
[[i,j] for i in range(3) for j in 'abc']
```

a syntax error:

```
[i,j for i in range(3) for j in 'abc']
```

Which is inconsistent (IMHO) and confusing with dictionary comprehensions syntax:

```
>>> {i:j for i,j in enumerate('abcdef')}
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e', 5: 'f'}
```

And a set of tuples:

```
>>> {(i,j) for i,j in enumerate('abcdef')}
set([(0, 'a'), (4, 'e'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (5, 'f'), (3, 'd')])
```

As Óscar López stated, you can just pass the enumerate tuple directly:

```
>>> [t for t in enumerate('abcdef') ] 
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd'), (4, 'e'), (5, 'f')]
```

Answer (score 33):

Or, if you don't insist on using a list comprehension:

```
>>> mylist = ["a","b","c","d"]
>>> list(enumerate(mylist))
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd')]
```

Answer (score 12):

If you're using long lists, it appears the list comprehension's faster, not to mention more readable.

```
~$ python -mtimeit -s"mylist = ['a','b','c','d']" "list(enumerate(mylist))"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.61 usec per loop
~$ python -mtimeit -s"mylist = ['a','b','c','d']" "[(i, j) for i, j in enumerate(mylist)]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.978 usec per loop
~$ python -mtimeit -s"mylist = ['a','b','c','d']" "[t for t in enumerate(mylist)]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.767 usec per loop
```

Comment: +1 I did not test it, but I'll bet `[t for t in enumerate(my list)]` is even faster.

Comment: These timings are *very* misleading. For such a short input, the higher fixed overhead of invoking the `list` constructor (overhead that has come down dramatically in later versions of Python) is not made up by the lower per-item overhead consuming the output of `enumerate`. But even when listcomps win it doesn't matter; the work done for such a small input is trivial no matter what, you care about losses on meaningful amounts of work. The listcomp will *definitely* lose for a large enough input, with the threshold for "large enough" varying based on the version of Python you're using.

Comment: I redid the timings, without changing the number of items involved, on Python 3.11.6 (dropping the one with unpacking, it's definitionally slower to split up the `tuple` and recreate it than to reuse it), and adding 3.5's `[*enumerate(mylist)]` unpacking syntax. `list(enumerate(mylist))` was 189 nsec per loop, the listcomp was 265 nsec per loop, and `[*enumerate(mylist)]` beat them both at 164 nsec per loop (doing the same thing as `list(enumerate(mylist))`, but with dedicated bytecode to bypass the faster, but still slower than it could be, generic function call path).

Answer (score 11):

Here's a way to do it:

```
>>> mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> [item for item in enumerate(mylist)]
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd')]
```

Alternatively, you can do:

```
>>> [(i, j) for i, j in enumerate(mylist)]
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd')]
```

The reason you got an error was that you were missing the () around `i` and `j` to make it a tuple.

Answer (score 6):

Be explicit about the tuples.

```
[(i, j) for (i, j) in enumerate(mylist)]
```

Answer (score 0):

All great answer guys. I know the question here is specific to enumeration but how about something like this, just another perspective

```
from itertools import izip, count
a = ["5", "6", "1", "2"]
tupleList = list( izip( count(), a ) )
print(tupleList)
```

It becomes more powerful, if one has to iterate multiple lists in parallel in terms of performance. Just a thought

```
a = ["5", "6", "1", "2"]
b = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
tupleList = list( izip( count(), a, b ) )
print(tupleList)
```