# Python reduce a list by order

Tags: python, list

Say I have a list [10, 5, 7] and I want to reduce it to something that indicates the relative orders [3, 1, 2]. I don't know how to convert this in Python.

Comment: That's not really a reduction; "reduce" usually means you wind up with fewer values than you started with (most often 1 from a list of many, in fact).

Comment: Check this one out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777271/python-using-enumerate-inside-list-comprehension

Look into dictionary and enumerate.

Comment: @PatrickKostjens Really disgusting brute force approach where I iterate from 1 to the max value in the list and then check off the orders as I encounter them, but it's super slow and probably not worth using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
start = [10, 5, 7]
```

Sort it

```
step1 = sorted(start) #if you have duplicates, sorted(set(start)) to uniquify
```

Make a lookup table

```
lookup = {v:i for i,v in enumerate(step1,1)}
```

Make your new list.

```
[lookup[x] for x in start]
Out[9]: [3, 1, 2]
```

This is O(nlogn) instead of the O(n**2) solution using repeated `index` searches.  Timings:

```
test = [randrange(0,10000) for _ in range(10000)]

def f():
    std = sorted(test)
    return [std.index(e)+1 for e in test]

def g():
    step1 = sorted(test)
    lookup = {v:i for i,v in enumerate(step1,1)}
    return [lookup[x] for x in test]

%timeit f()
1 loops, best of 3: 1.17 s per loop

%timeit g()
100 loops, best of 3: 6.58 ms per loop
```

Comment: This answer assumes the input list contains unique values.

Comment: @SimeonVisser yes.  Added a comment to address that.

Answer (score 6):

Try this, assuming there are no duplicate elements in the list:

```
lst = [10, 5, 7]
std = sorted(lst)

[std.index(e)+1 for e in lst]
=> [3, 1, 2]
```

Comment: This is O(n**2) so depending on OP's needs may be too "brute force".

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [10,5,7]
b = sorted(a)
newList = []
for i in a:
  newList.append(b.index(i))

print newList
```

Note that the output is [2,0,1] because the list is zero based, you could modify the code to append b.index(i)+1 if you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [29]: L=[10,5,7]

In [30]: %paste
inds = {}
for v,k in enumerate(sorted(L),1):
  if k not in inds:
    inds[k] = []
  inds[k].append(v)
answer = [inds[k].pop() for k in L]

## -- End pasted text --

In [31]: answer
Out[31]: [3, 1, 2]
```