# Trying to use enumerate() on a string with lines not surrounded by quotes in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to use `enumerate()` on a string already in memory (thus not from file), which string has comma separated values (or space, but uniformly, i.e. not mix of comma and spaces).
Basically I just want to get the whole line n, something quite similar to the first part of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777271/python-using-enumerate-inside-list-comprehension) question.

If I do a `print` on my string (before entering the function), it shows something like this:

```
89,abc,def01,ghi23
01,jkl,mno45,pqr67
```

however this code does not work, presumably because my lines are not individually surrounded by quotes:

```
def pickline(thestring, whatline):
  for i, line in enumerate(thestring):
    if i == whatline:
      return line
```

Question: what should I do to get this right ?

**edit** The expected output should be:

```
# string
89,abc,def01,ghi23
# if whatline value is 0,
# or string
01,jkl,mno45,pqr67
# if whatline value is 1,
# etc.
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: iterating a string goes character-by-character. Quotes have nothing at all to do with it. If you need to iterate over the chunks between commas, use `.split(",")` or the `csv` module.

Comment: Does your string contain newlines, or are the two lines of your example input from two different strings?

Comment: Printing on screen goes line by line, so I assumed it ends with \n, but I checked anyway: I wrote the raw string to a file and inside the file the lines are separated by 0x0D and 0x0A; I am on Windows and don't know if the OS intervenes when saving a raw text, I suppose not (?).

Comment: @thefourtheye Sorry, I thought it was clear enough saying "I just want to get the whole line n", but I get the point, will do more clearly in the future, as in the **edit** above (hopefully).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to split the string into lines first.

```
for i, line in enumerate(thestring.splitlines()):
```

However, a better way to do this is to do this:

```
def pickline(thestring, whatline):
    return thestring.splitlines()[whatline]
```