# How do I use Enumerate to to make each word into a number not each character

Tags: python, enumerate

So I need to make a program that gets the user to enter a sentence, and then the code turns that sentence into numbers corresponding to it's position in the list, I cam across the command Enumerate here: [Python using enumerate inside list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777271/python-using-enumerate-inside-list-comprehension) but this gets every character not every word, so this is my code so far, can anyone help me fix this?

```
list = []
lists = ""
sentence= input("Enter a sentence").lower()
print(sentence)
list.append(lists)
print(lists)
for i,j in enumerate(sentence):
    print (i,j)
```

Comment: It is not clear exactly what you want to do here. Can you give some sample input and expected output?

Comment: `enumerate(sentence.split())`

Comment: So i'll just give you a simple run through of what it does so first the user enters a sentence, then the program prints this sentence and converts the words to numbers, but in the position it is in on the list, so for example i enter "Hello world" the code should print "1 2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sentence` is string, so it is split to single chars. You should split it to words first:

```
for i,j in enumerate(sentence.split(' ')):
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
>>> sentence = 'I like Moive'
>>> sentence = sentence.lower()
>>> sentence = sentence.split()
>>> for i, j in enumerate(sentence):
...         print(i, j)
```