# How do I add an integer to just some numbers in a list?

Tags: python

I have a list and I want to add an integer to every value in the list, past the fifth value.

```
PageNumbers = [30, 50, 80, 120, 160, 200, 240, 280]
PageNumbers = [x+100 for x in PageNumbers]
```

How do I make it `PageNumbers = if PageNumber[index] > 5, then [x+100 for x in PageNumbers] else PageNumber[index]`.

My desired output is `[30, 50, 80, 120, 160, 300, 340, 380]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide the list into two parts:

```
PageNumbers = PageNumbers[:5] + [x+100 for x in PageNumbers[5:]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out `enumerate` to grab both the index and the value while iterating a list.

This will allow you to do something like the below:

```
PageNumbers = [30, 50, 80, 120, 160, 200, 240, 280]
PageNumbers = [val + 100 if idx > 4 else val for idx, val in enumerate(PageNumbers)]
```

*Note that I actually used `idx > 4` which means anything past the 5th value (0-index based) as you noted and used in your example. You can, of course, change to use whichever index you'd like.

See a short post and discussion on `enumerate` here:
[Python using enumerate inside list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777271/python-using-enumerate-inside-list-comprehension)

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(5, len(PageNumbers)):
    PageNumbers[i] += 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Just assign it back

```
PageNumbers[5:]=[x +100 for x in PageNumbers[5:]]
PageNumbers
[30, 50, 80, 120, 160, 300, 340, 380]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) and the [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) builtin:

```
>>> PageNumbers = [30, 50, 80, 120, 160, 200, 240, 280]
>>> [x + 100 if i > 4 else x for i, x in enumerate(PageNumbers)]
[30, 50, 80, 120, 160, 300, 340, 380]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an example using NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

PageNumbers = np.array([30, 50, 80, 120, 160, 200, 240, 280])

PageNumbers[5:] += 100

print(PageNumbers)
#=> [ 30  50  80 120 160 300 340 380]
```